# Not selected tabs Bottom Bar are not showing using Xamarin.Forms Shell (only Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm testing Xamarin.Forms Shell. This is my `AppShell.xaml`:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PhotosXamarin.Views"
       x:Class="PhotosXamarin.AppShell"
       BackgroundColor="#2A2A2A"
       TitleColor="White">
    <TabBar>
        <views:PhotosView
            IconImageSource="camera"
            Title="Photos" />
        <views:FavoritePhotosView
            IconImageSource="favorite"
            Title="Favorites" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

The problem is that not selected tab icons are not shown:

[image]

Anyone is facing the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I test on Xamarin.Froms, it works well. Could you provide the code sample for us to test?

Comment: Of course: https://github.com/gentilijuanmanuel/cross-platform-competition/tree/xamarin-stuff/xamarin/PhotosXamarin

Comment: I tried with Font Icons also, and the result is the same :(

Comment: I've had the same issue and filed a bug.  Granted I'm using tabbed page and you're using shell but I suspect the same underneath?  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8069

Comment: @JuanManuelGentili Any update using the latest xf version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't work with Xamarin anymore, but you can download the repo I linked before and test it upgrading the XF version!